# updating function arguments python in each iterations

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to update my function arguments after each iteration but failed to do so. Kindly check my code because I am new to python language. My task is to calculate xps, (represents collection of positions) and v2ps, (represents collection of velocities) after each iteration and want to plot them against each other. Basic this program represents the collision of objects moving vertical down and one of object also collide with plane above which they are moving.

```
acc_grav = 10
m1 =float(input(" Input mass of ball one, m1: "))
m2 =float(input(" Input mass of ball two, m2: "))
time_steps =10000
num_coll_bounce = 0
num_ball_coll = 0
eps=1.e-6

def ball_coll(x1_old,v1_old,x2_old,v2_old,time_ball_coll):
v1 = v1_old - acc_grav*time_ball_coll
v2 = v2_old - acc_grav*time_ball_coll
x1 = x1_old + time_ball_coll*v1_old - 0.5*acc_grav*(time_ball_coll)**2
x2 = x2_old + time_ball_coll*v2_old - 0.5*acc_grav*(time_ball_coll)**2 
v1_ball_coll = (v1*(m1-m2)+(2*m2*v2))/(m1+m2) 
v2_ball_coll = (v2*(m2-m1)+(2*m1*v1))/(m1+m2) 
cumlv2=v2
return [v1,v2,x1,x2,v1_ball_coll,v2_ball_coll]

def floor_coll(x1_old,v1_old,x2_old,v2_old,time_floor_coll):
v1 = v1_old - acc_grav*time_floor_coll
v2 = v2_old - acc_grav*time_floor_coll
x1 = 0 #at the time of bonuce
x2 = x2_old + time_floor_coll*v2_old - 0.5*acc_grav*time_floor_coll**2
#update velocities following rules for collision with walls 
v1_bounce = -v1 
v2_bounce = v2
return [v1,v2,x1,x2,v1_bounce,v2_bounce]

for i in range(0, 10):
    x1_0 = 1
    x2_0 = 3 - (i-1)*0.1
    v1_0 = 2
    v2_0 = 2*v1_0
    xps = []
    v2ps = []

   for n in range (time_steps-1):
      time_ball_coll = (x2_0-x1_0)/(v1_0 - v2_0)
      time_floor_coll = (v1_0 + (v1_0**2 + 2*acc_grav*x1_0)**1/2)/acc_grav

        if ((time_ball_coll - time_floor_coll)<eps and v1_0 - v2_0 > 0):
           num_coll_bounce = num_coll_bounce + 1
           num_ball_coll = num_ball_coll + 1
           ball_coll(x1_0,v1_0,x2_0,v2_0,time_ball_coll)

           #xps[n] = x2_0
           #v2ps(n,num_ballcoll) = v2ini
           xps.append(x2_0)
           v2ps.append(v2_0) 


       else:
          num_coll_bounce = num_coll_bounce + 1
          floor_coll(x1_0,v1_0,x2_0,v2_0,time_floor_coll)
          #x1_old,v1_old,x2_old,v2_old,time_floor_coll = dd2

          x_1.append(x1_0)
          x_2.append(x2_0)
```

Comment: Please format your code. I attempted to do it via an edit, but it's not 100% clear what is and is not actually indented in your code, and indentation could potentially be part of the problem.

Comment: what is the `x_1` in the `x_1.append(x1_0)` at the end referring to?

Comment: I was just trying to save x1_0 in some new variable.

Comment: You're not doing anything with the results returned from `ball_coll` in your main loop. Is that intentional or the cause of your problem?

Comment: Python passes most argument by value, except for mutable arguments such as a list or dict. So values passed to a function are usually not altered inside the function: use the returned value instead.

Comment: Evert:  Yes it is intentional